# Getting elevation at particular coordinate (lat/lon) programmatically (but offline)?

Tags: python, software-recommendations, latitude-longitude, elevation, api

I would prefer something in python (but I would settle for any programming language) and something that I could install on my own server so the only limitations would be hardware (no throttling, no daily request limits, etc). i.e. I'm not interested in using a hosted service like Google Maps API.

What I want to be able to do is something like:

```
for location in locations_data_store:
  location.elevation = some_module.lookup_elevation(location.lat, location.lon)
  location.persist()
```

Or, it could be more involved than that. I don't mind making a REST API request, parsing some JSON, or in some other way more complex programmatically.

Comment: What GIS software/environment are you planning on using?  

The National Map Viewer has elevation data from USGS in 1/3 arc sec for most of the USA.  https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/

Comment: No software, this is purely programmatic on a server with no UI. I have a big list of coords in a DB that I want to add elevation data to.

Comment: What server are you using (e.g. Oracle, PostgresSQL, etc)?

Comment: Linux, data store will likely be NoSQL, maybe mongo or dynamodb.

Comment: I added an example of code of what I want to do. The data store shouldn't really matter. I may end up also wanting to do this on the fly without the DB as well. I just want to be able to give an API lat/lon and get back the corresponding elevation. I can download and install the API and the elevation data onto the server and get them hooked up together, I just need to know what's the best source for the data and what API would know how to use that data to extract elevation info.

Comment: You seem to be asking for both data and software recommendations which means you are asking two broad questions. I think you should start by making it clear whether it is software or data that you want to ask about in this question.

Comment: I would like to know what API to use or what the possibilities are if there are multiple. But as I understand it the API would not be useful unless it has data to work with? The API would need to get the elevation data from somewhere?

Comment: I removed everything related to what data to use with the API so this question is now solely asking about which API to use to get elevation information. Once I have a recommended API I'll start a new question to ask about what would be the best data sources to provide to that API.

Comment: I think you're confused as to what an API is.  An API is the framework for communicating with a server/environment that contains the information/process that you want to leverage.  Any API with elevation data will have that data within the server and you will make a call to it to get that data out.  Your script will need to communicate with the API.  Here's some info on the Google Maps API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro

Comment: I want to host the API myself. For example, OSM has a read-only API called Overpass. You can install Overpass on your own server, hook it up to a local copy of the OSM DB and access that API via overpy. You could access the API with a variety of other languages, just overpy provides a little layer on top of the REST API so you don't have to deal with the low-level details of submitting the query and parsing the results into python objects.

Comment: Maybe I don't need a separate API. I'm not sure. I don't know how querying elevation data works. I'm looking for some sort of programmatic interface to get the elevation for a specific coord that doesn't rely on a 3rd party service (like google maps api) that is rate-limited. I want to be able to max it out and throw more hardware at it if its not fast enough. I'm guessing at a minimum that means I need a code library and some elevation data.

Comment: I've tried to update the question and description to better follow the rules and to be more clear as to what I'm looking for. I guess my main problem might be that I'm a programmer and not a GIS expert ;)

Comment: Please **edit the question** to contain your question.  Eight long comments is eight comments too many.

Comment: I have edited the question and description multiple times as commenters have pointed out different needs for clarification. The question & description as it stands now is the entirety of my question. Is there any information you feel it is lacking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`rasterio`](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) library:

```
import rasterio

coords = ((147.363,-36.419), (147.361,-36.430))
elevation = 'srtm_66_20.tif'

with rasterio.open(elevation) as src:
    vals = src.sample(coords)
    for val in vals:
        print(val[0]) #val is an array of values, 1 element 
                      #per band. src is a single band raster 
                      #so we only need val[0]
```

The example above uses the [SRTM](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=SRTM) digital elevation model (DEM), but there are others available depending on your area of interest and resolution requirements.

Note the example is simple as SRTM data is available in a geographic coordinate system, there are a few more steps if your DEM is in a different projection.

Comment: Seems like SRTM comes with multiple 'tif' files--how do you know which one to use?

Comment: Would this work for any data source that is provided as a 'tif' file as long as the coords are adjusted to the correct projection?

Comment: It would work for any raster format that rasterio can read

Comment: You can look into mosaicing individual rasters

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially what I ended up doing, just wrapped into a package that knows where the individual elevation files are located and can use the input coords to determine which file to use. I ended up going with the data from https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/national-elevation-dataset-ned-1-3-arc-second-downloadable-data-collection-national-geospatial

Answer (score -1):

For the future users' convinience, when you provide lat lon in get_elevation function, it gives the elevation.

```
import rasterio
elevation_file = 'Dem.tif'
def get_elevation(lat, lon):
    coords = ((lat,lon), (lat,lon))
    with rasterio.open(elevation_file) as src:
        vals = src.sample(coords)
        for val in vals:
            elevation=val[0]
            return elevation
get_elevation(34, 36)
```